# Creating a Windows to Go ISO from an installed system

Tags: windows-10, windows-to-go

Is it possible to create a [Windows to Go](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/itpro/windows/plan/windows-to-go-overview) (WTG) disc image from a pre-installed OS?

My corporate laptop has finally been upgraded to Windows 10, WTG has been approved for use by our information security team and the feature is enabled within the control panel.

Within our company we use [System Center Configuration Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/cloud-platform/system-center-configuration-manager) to push OS installs over the network to devices, so during OS install we never actually see an installation media, physical or digital.

I got in touch with our IT dept to see if there is an image available to build a WTG USB stick but the response was effectively

> We don't have the resource (manpower, money) to create specific WTG images. Although it
>   is enabled as a feature, you're basically on your own.

Therfore, I am curious to whether I can build a WTG stick without a Windows image, but use the currently installed OS to build a configured image.

I do have a personal copy of Windows 10 Ent, but I would assume (and can't find anything to the suggest otherwise) this would build a 'standard' Windows 10 Ent image, not specific to my corporate device (with the associated VPNs, enterprise apps etc specific to my laptop) even if I built the bootable USB drive on my corporate laptop.

Comment: The first thing you would have to do is generate a .wim image of the system using DISM

Answer (score 0):

I use [AOMEI Backupper Standard](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html) to make a drive image of the Win10 installation, then restore the drive image to the USB drive, checking the "Restore system to other location" option before proceeding. I have to set the BIOS on the target computer to boot in UEFI (i.e., not Legacy) mode and turn off Secure Boot. There can be [various settings to tweak](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2019/09/17/windows-to-go/#UPD), such as adjusting the power settings when booting a laptop with a USB drive capturing a desktop installation.